# Internationalization string comparision

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

I want to apply internationalization in my web application. For that i am storing some static labels fields in properties files. And access that properties files using jquery-i18n-properties plugins. But the problem is that in my jQuery code i am comparing some string which is coming from server side. Now the problem is that how can i check that label value is 'Foo'? In short i want to do following things.

```
    var labelValue = "フー";
    if(labelValue == "Foo"){
      //then do something
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't!

If you're trying to hard-code comparisons of displayed values in javascript, you can't make your code multi-language compliant.

There are a few possibilities:

1) Translate your comparisons

So, if you want to compare `lavelValue` that you mentioned, you'll have to find a way to translate that correctly and compare the actual value to the translated value.  One common way to do this is to make files that contain your hard-coded strings in the different languages.  When you change languages, change javascript files.  (Obviously a bit more complicated than that, but that's the idea.)

2) Compare against non-translated data

In other words, don't compare against `labelValue` if it's going to have translated words.  Instead, store the "invariant" value and compare against the non-translated ("invariant") value.

Internationalization is a pain.  Good luck